# Could this complex find-and-replace be done as a one-liner?

Tags: python, regex, awk, replace, sed

Suppose I have the following text:   (note that the examples have been simplified since they were originally written)

```
\begin{align} E_{i,j} \left( \Phi_{i-1,j-1} + \Phi_{i-1,j} + \Phi_{i-1,j+1} + \Phi_{i,j-1} + \Phi_{i,j} + \Phi_{i,j+1} + \Phi_{i+1,j-1} + \Phi_{i+1,j} + \Phi_{i+1,j+1} \right) \end{align}
```

I have two tasks:

- Replace each `i` in the brackets with a given value (e.g. `2`).
- Replace each `j` in the brackets with a given value (e.g. `6`).

Constraints:

- The script should not naively replace *any* `i` or *any* `j`, but only the ones within the `_{*,*}` pattern.
- There are other constructs between braces (e.g. `\begin{align}`) that should not be affected.
- Wherever there is a mathematical operator (e.g. `i+1`, `j-2`, etc.), the replacement should be the numeric result of the operation. (The math would only ever be addition or subtraction.)
- All instances within a line should be replaced -- not just the first instance on a line.
- I could also replace `i` or `j` with a alphanumeric pattern (e.g. `i` --> `N_r`. In this case, the substitution is simple and straightforward.
- I want to be able to replace either `i`, or `j`, *or both* with values.
- I need to do this on multiple lines. (I use a text file.)

#### Example outputs

The example text (above), with `i` --> `3`, would become:

```
\begin{align} E_{3,j} \left( \Phi_{2,j-1} + \Phi_{2,j} + \Phi_{2,j+1} + \Phi_{3,j-1} + \Phi_{3,j} + \Phi_{3,j+1} + \Phi_{4,j-1} + \Phi_{4,j} + \Phi_{4,j+1} \right) \end{align}
```

The example text (above), with `j` --> `5`, would become:

```
\begin{align} E_{i,5} \left( \Phi_{i-1,4} + \Phi_{i-1,5} + \Phi_{i-1,6} + \Phi_{i,4} + \Phi_{i,5} + \Phi_{i,6} + \Phi_{i+1,4} + \Phi_{i+1,5} + \Phi_{i+1,6} \right) \end{align}
```

The example text (above), with `i` --> `3` AND `j` --> `5`, would become:

```
\begin{align} E_{3,5} \left( \Phi_{2,4} + \Phi_{2,5} + \Phi_{2,6} + \Phi_{3,4} + \Phi_{3,5} + \Phi_{3,6} + \Phi_{4,4} + \Phi_{4,5} + \Phi_{4,6} \right) \end{align}
```

The example text (above), with `i` --> `N_r`, would become:

```
\begin{align} E_{N_r,j} \left( \Phi_{N_r-1,j-1} + \Phi_{N_r-1,j} + \Phi_{N_r-1,j+1} + \Phi_{N_r,j-1} + \Phi_{N_r,j} + \Phi_{N_r,j+1} + \Phi_{N_r+1,j-1} + \Phi_{N_r+1,j} + \Phi_{N_r+1,j+1} \right) \end{align}
```

#### My question: Can this be done as a one-liner (perhaps using `awk`), and if so, how?

If not, how few lines would it take in either `awk`, `sed`, or `python` (or similar)?

I know python handles command-line parameters well and could easily evaluate the math, but the tokenization seems hard.

I think my difficulty is (1) how to get `sed` or `awk` to take a variable number of command-line parameters (the substitutions; either one or both), and (2) how to get the behavior to change between a substitution being numeric (and having to do math) and symbolic (and having the substitution be text-only).

Tie-breaker goes to the version that can go backwards for symbolic characters. For example, if the input text were the following:

```
\begin{align} E_{N_r,j} \left( \Phi_{N_r-1,j-1} + \Phi_{N_r-1,j} + \Phi_{N_r-1,j+1} + \Phi_{N_r,j-1} + \Phi_{N_r,j} + \Phi_{N_r,j+1} + \Phi_{N_r+1,j-1} + \Phi_{N_r+1,j} + \Phi_{N_r+1,j+1} \right) \end{align}
```

and I wanted to replace `N_r` with `i`, then the result would be the following:

```
\begin{align} E_{N_r,j} \left( \Phi_{N_r-1,j-1} + \Phi_{N_r-1,j} + \Phi_{N_r-1,j+1} + \Phi_{N_r,j-1} + \Phi_{N_r,j} + \Phi_{N_r,j+1} + \Phi_{N_r+1,j-1} + \Phi_{N_r+1,j} + \Phi_{N_r+1,j+1} \right) \end{align}
```

Bonus points for being able to replace symbols with other symbols that may include math, and doing the math right. For example, it should replace `i` with `i-1`, such that if it finds `_{i-1,j}`, it converts it into ``_{i-2,j}`.

Comment: Why should it have to be done as a one liner? Forcing yourself on one line is never a good idea.

Comment: I'm open to it being done in multiple lines! :-)

Comment: sed is probably not the best choice if you want it to do the actual math (`i-2`, `i=3`, into `1`)

Comment: @depperm you can use `sed -e "s/$i+1/$((i+1))/g"` or `sed -e "s/i+1/$((i+1))/g"` for example

Comment: @EdMorton: The examples I gave are almost complete -- I did not give an example of changing `j` to a symbolic variable. They are easily verifiable. They could be simplified. I'll do that now.

Comment: @EdMorton: The input is given in the first code/text box. There are two kinds of substitutions (numeric and symbolic) for two different variables (`i` and `j`), plus the case of substituting both variables at once instead of just one. The output depends on the substitutions made, so there is not one, *single* output for the input text. I provided four test cases with four independent outputs which test four of the twelve different test cases. The test cases share the main input text, but differ in that they make different substitutions -- let me know if I can offer further assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    while ( match($0,/{[^}]+/) ) {
        tgt = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
        if (i != "") { gsub(/i/,i,tgt) }
        if (j != "") { gsub(/j/,j,tgt) }
        split(tgt,halves,/,/)
        for (h in halves) {
            if ( halves[h] ~ /^[0-9]+[+-][0-9]+$/ ) {
                split(halves[h],quarts,/[+-]/)
                halves[h] = quarts[1] + (halves[h]~/+/ ? 1 : -1)*quarts[2]
            }
        }
        printf "%s%s", substr($0,1,RSTART), halves[1] "," halves[2]
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}

$ awk -v i=3 -f tst.awk file
E_{3,j} \left( \Phi_{2,j-1} + \Phi_{2,j} + \Phi_{2,j+1} + \Phi_{3,j-1} + \Phi_{3,j} + \Phi_{3,j+1} + \Phi_{4,j-1} + \Phi_{4,j} + \Phi_{4,j+1} \right)

$ awk -v j=5 -f tst.awk file
E_{i,5} \left( \Phi_{i-1,4} + \Phi_{i-1,5} + \Phi_{i-1,6} + \Phi_{i,4} + \Phi_{i,5} + \Phi_{i,6} + \Phi_{i+1,4} + \Phi_{i+1,5} + \Phi_{i+1,6} \right)

$ awk -v i=3 -v j=5 -f tst.awk file
E_{3,5} \left( \Phi_{2,4} + \Phi_{2,5} + \Phi_{2,6} + \Phi_{3,4} + \Phi_{3,5} + \Phi_{3,6} + \Phi_{4,4} + \Phi_{4,5} + \Phi_{4,6} \right)

$ awk -v i=N_r -f tst.awk file
E_{N_r,j} \left( \Phi_{N_r-1,j-1} + \Phi_{N_r-1,j} + \Phi_{N_r-1,j+1} + \Phi_{N_r,j-1} + \Phi_{N_r,j} + \Phi_{N_r,j+1} + \Phi_{N_r+1,j-1} + \Phi_{N_r+1,j} + \Phi_{N_r+1,j+1} \right)
```

Given your updated requirements:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    while ( match($0,/_{[-+ij0-9]+,[-+ij0-9]+/) ) {
        tgt = substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)
        if (i != "") { gsub(/i/,i,tgt) }
        if (j != "") { gsub(/j/,j,tgt) }
        split(tgt,halves,/,/)
        for (h in halves) {
            if ( halves[h] ~ /^[0-9]+[+-][0-9]+$/ ) {
                split(halves[h],quarts,/[+-]/)
                halves[h] = quarts[1] + (halves[h]~/+/ ? 1 : -1)*quarts[2]
            }
        }
        printf "%s%s", substr($0,1,RSTART+1), halves[1] "," halves[2]
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}

$ awk -v i=3 -v j=5 -f tst.awk file
\begin{align} E_{3,5} \left( \Phi_{2,4} + \Phi_{2,5} + \Phi_{2,6} + \Phi_{3,4} + \Phi_{3,5} + \Phi_{3,6} + \Phi_{4,4} + \Phi_{4,5} + \Phi_{4,6} \right) \end{align}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's close, but if there are other things in brackets, it adds a comma. For example: if there is text like `\begin{align}`, it spits out `\begin{align,}. I don't know awk syntax well enough to diagnose it, but is it perhaps the regex in the second line (`match($0,/{[^}]+/)`)? It should only match things that start with an underscore, then left curly brace, [i], comma, [j], and finally a right curly brace (`_{A,B}`, where A and B are the useful bits). How could that be fixed?

Comment: Thanks again for your time and attention. I followed your suggestion, but then `echo "\begin{align} E_{i,j}" | awk -v j=1 tst.awk` still gives `\begin{align,} E_{i,1}` as the result -- note the comma after `align`.

Comment: I added a modified solution to my answer. Try it now.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a bash function and use `sed`

```
convert(){
    re='^[0-9]+$'
    if [[ $1 =~ $re ]] && [[ $2 =~ $re ]]; then
        sed -r -e "s/\bi\b/$1/g" -e "s/\bj\b/$2/g" | sed -e "s/$1+1/$(($1+1))/g" -e  "s/$1-1/$(($1-1))/g" -e "s/$2+1/$(($2+1))/g" -e  "s/$2-1/$(($2-1))/g";
    elif [[ $1 =~ $re ]]; then
        sed -r -e "s/\bi\b/$1/g" -e "s/\bj\b/$2/g" | sed -e "s/$1+1/$(($1+1))/g" -e  "s/$1-1/$(($1-1))/g";
    elif [[ $2 =~ $re ]]; then
        sed -r -e "s/\bi\b/$1/g" -e "s/\bj\b/$2/g" | sed -e "s/$2+1/$(($2+1))/g" -e  "s/$2-1/$(($2-1))/g";
    else
        sed -r -e "s/\bi\b/$1/g" -e "s/\bj\b/$2/g";
    fi
}
```

where `input` file is,

```
E_{i,j} \left( e^{-1,-1}_{i,j} \Phi_{i-1,j-1} + e^{-1,0}_{i,j} \Phi_{i-1,j} + e^{-1,+1}_{i,j} \Phi_{i-1,j+1} + e^{0,-1}_{i,j} \Phi_{i,j-1} + e^{0,0}_{i,j} \Phi_{i,j} + e^{0,+1}_{i,j} \Phi_{i,j+1} + e^{+1,-1}_{i,j} \Phi_{i+1,j-1} + e^{+1,0}_{i,j} \Phi_{i+1,j} + e^{+1,+1}_{i,j} \Phi_{i+1,j+1}  \right)
```

**test1**

```
cat input | convert 3 j
```

you get,

```
E_{3,j} \left( e^{-1,-1}_{3,j} \Phi_{2,j-1} + e^{-1,0}_{3,j} \Phi_{2,j} + e^{-1,+1}_{3,j} \Phi_{2,j+1} + e^{0,-1}_{3,j} \Phi_{3,j-1} + e^{0,0}_{3,j} \Phi_{3,j} + e^{0,+1}_{3,j} \Phi_{3,j+1} + e^{+1,-1}_{3,j} \Phi_{4,j-1} + e^{+1,0}_{3,j} \Phi_{4,j} + e^{+1,+1}_{3,j} \Phi_{4,j+1}  \right)
```

**test 2**

```
cat input | convert i 5
```

you get,

```
E_{i,5} \left( e^{-1,-1}_{i,5} \Phi_{i-1,4} + e^{-1,0}_{i,5} \Phi_{i-1,5} + e^{-1,+1}_{i,5} \Phi_{i-1,6} + e^{0,-1}_{i,5} \Phi_{i,4} + e^{0,0}_{i,5} \Phi_{i,5} + e^{0,+1}_{i,5} \Phi_{i,6} + e^{+1,-1}_{i,5} \Phi_{i+1,4} + e^{+1,0}_{i,5} \Phi_{i+1,5} + e^{+1,+1}_{i,5} \Phi_{i+1,6}  \right)
```

**test 3**

```
cat input | convert 3 5
```

you get,

```
E_{3,5} \left( e^{-1,-1}_{3,5} \Phi_{2,4} + e^{-1,0}_{3,5} \Phi_{2,5} + e^{-1,+1}_{3,5} \Phi_{2,6} + e^{0,-1}_{3,5} \Phi_{3,4} + e^{0,0}_{3,5} \Phi_{3,5} + e^{0,+1}_{3,5} \Phi_{3,6} + e^{+1,-1}_{3,5} \Phi_{4,4} + e^{+1,0}_{3,5} \Phi_{4,5} + e^{+1,+1}_{3,5} \Phi_{4,6}  \right)
```

**test 4**

```
cat input | convert N_r j
```

you get,

```
E_{N_r,j} \left( e^{-1,-1}_{N_r,j} \Phi_{N_r-1,j-1} + e^{-1,0}_{N_r,j} \Phi_{N_r-1,j} + e^{-1,+1}_{N_r,j} \Phi_{N_r-1,j+1} + e^{0,-1}_{N_r,j} \Phi_{N_r,j-1} + e^{0,0}_{N_r,j} \Phi_{N_r,j} + e^{0,+1}_{N_r,j} \Phi_{N_r,j+1} + e^{+1,-1}_{N_r,j} \Phi_{N_r+1,j-1} + e^{+1,0}_{N_r,j} \Phi_{N_r+1,j} + e^{+1,+1}_{N_r,j} \Phi_{N_r+1,j+1}  \right)
```